# Android set icon to customTabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

i'm wrote simple code to have custom TabHost in application. this class extended from ABS and fregment, this code work correctly and i want to set icon for tabs, but i can not do it.

```
public class ActivitySmsSendSelectorMain extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    TabHost     mTabHost;
    ViewPager   mViewPager;
    TabsAdapter mTabsAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sms_send_selector_main);
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("ContactView")
                .setIndicator(UC.getResourcesText(R.string.abs_sms_send_selector_contact_view)),
                FragmentSample1.class, null);
        mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("MobileArchive")
                .setIndicator(UC.getResourcesText(R.string.abs_sms_send_selector_archive_mobile)),
                FragmentSample2.class, null);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString("tab", mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag());
    }

    public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
            implements TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
        private final Context            mContext;
        private final TabHost            mTabHost;
        private final ViewPager          mViewPager;
        private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();
        static final class TabInfo {

            private final String   tag;
            private final Class<?> clss;
            private final Bundle   args;


            TabInfo(String _tag, Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
                tag = _tag;
                clss = _class;
                args = _args;
            }
        }
        static class DummyTabFactory implements TabHost.TabContentFactory {
            private final Context mContext;
            public DummyTabFactory(Context context) {
                mContext = context;
            }
            @Override
            public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                View v = new View(mContext);
                v.setMinimumWidth(0);
                v.setMinimumHeight(0);
                return v;
            }
        }

        public TabsAdapter(FragmentActivity activity, TabHost tabHost, ViewPager pager) {
            super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
            mContext = activity;
            mTabHost = tabHost;
            mViewPager = pager;
            mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        }
        public void addTab(TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            tabSpec.setContent(new DummyTabFactory(mContext));
            String tag = tabSpec.getTag();

            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(tag, clss, args);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mTabs.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
            return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            int position = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            TabWidget widget = mTabHost.getTabWidget();
            int oldFocusability = widget.getDescendantFocusability();
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(position);
            widget.setDescendantFocusability(oldFocusability);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    }
```

i'm try to change mTabHost to :

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("ContactView")
                .setIndicator(UC.getResourcesText(R.string.abs_sms_send_selector_contact_view),
                        G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_user)),
                FragmentSmsSendSelectorContactView.class, null);
```

but it doesnt show icon into tab

Comment: use mTabHost.setIndicator("The Tab",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.yourxmlfile))

Comment: @BornToWin my wrote code in `mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("ContactView")
                .setIndicator(UC.getResourcesText(R.string.abs_sms_send_selector_contact_view)),
                FragmentSample1.class, null);` dont support `res`, how to add this ability my code?

Comment: @Born To Win post updated, please review that

Comment: What is UC ang G in your code?

Comment: @BornToWin UC is UtulityClass and G is class extends from application

Comment: Actually i am not getting your problem.please mentioned yor problem in one line so i can help you.

Comment: @BornToWin problem is my set icon to TabHot dont show after trying to use `G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.app_user)),` in code